# How to add "" in to string.Format in C#

Tags: c#, string, format

I need to pass the folder path to the Python interface but spaces in the path make it complicated.
Example :
`Defect.py C:\TestImage\Images` works fine.
However, if there is a space in the path as below,

```
`Defect.py C:\**Test Image**\Images`
```

causes an error due to two separate parameters.

If I could pass it as :
`Defect.py "C:\**Test Image**\Images"` should work

So I am currently trying to use `string.Format("{0}")` to format this string with double quotations but does not work.
Please let me know how I could format the statement using `string.Format`. I need to use string.Format since there are multiple other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.Format("Defect.py \"C:\\{0}\\Images\"", "Test Image");
```

Bear in mind that the whole trick is to escape the character using the `\"` backslash escape character. The rest of it was just to show how to use the `string.Format`